# Excel VBA Macro to Merge Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file as follows:

```
A       1         E       A, 1, E
B                 F       B, F
C       2         G       C, 2, G
```

I need a Macro that will produce the results as shown in the fourth column.  Ultimately, it will merge the cells and place a comma between each value.  The file I have goes to column BX and sometimes CA so there are quite a few columns.  Any help is appreciated!  I'm using office 2007.
I have the following:

```
Sub Merge()
Dim outputText As String
Const delim = ","
On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In Selection
  outputText = outputText & cell.Value & delim
Next cell
With Selection
  .Clear
  .Cells(1).Value = outputText
  .Merge
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  .WrapText = True
End With
End Sub
```

But when I perform this macro on the second row, I get the following output: B,,F instead of B,F

Comment: Sure - what do you have so far?  Always better to include your current code.

Comment: I have the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some small changes

```
Sub Merge()

    Dim outputText As String, sep As String
    Dim cell As Range, rw As Range
    Const DELIM = ","

    outputText = ""
    sep = ""

    For Each rw in ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CA3").Rows

        For Each cell In rw.Cells
            If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
               outputText = outputText & sep & cell.Value
               sep = DELIM
            End If
        Next cell

        With rw
          .Clear
          .Cells(1).Value = outputText
          .Merge
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
          .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
          .WrapText = True
        End With

     Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! One more question. Is there anyway to run this for all data rows (the first three rows in my example)

Comment: Thank you from much Tim!